# python - should I dispose a socket after sending udp data?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, udp, python-sockets

I have a a method which listens to events, and everytime an event happens, it should send data to a socket (its udp, so I don't check if the data was received).

what I have in the event_handler is this:

```
    socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    socket.sendto(data, (IP, PORT))
```

It seems to me that I need to create a new socket **everytime** the event is called, because I don't know how much time will pass between two events, So having a **global socket variable** and send data on the event **doesn't guarantee** the socket is still up.

The thing is, because I create the socket everytime, should I dispose/close it after sending the data? what is the best way to dispose or close the socket after use?

Comment: What do you mean by "socket is still up"? Sockets, afaik, don't have "up" or "down" states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already explained by Rob, you do not necessarily need to create a new socket every time.

As per the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html):

> Sockets are automatically closed when they are garbage-collected, but
>   it is recommended to close() them explicitly, or to use a with
>   statement around them.

Hence, if you choose to create/close every time, you could do something like this:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as socket:
    socket.sendto(data, (IP, PORT))
```

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me that I need to create a new socket everytime the event is called,

No, it is OK to reuse the previous socket. Remember UDP sockekts are connectionless, so your concern about being disconnected doesn't apply.

> The thing is, because I create the socket everytime, should I dispose/close it after sending the data?

Yes, if you are going to create a zillion sockets, please close them as you go. Otherwise you will run out of file descriptor slots, a limited resource in your process.